# In Greg Bear's "Slant," what was the conspiracy trying to accomplish?

Tags: plot-device, slant

In Greg Bear's novel *Slant*, what was the villains' conspiracy trying to accomplish? What was their goal?

There are several plot threads. One is about a young prostitute who visits a client, who winds up killing himself for mysterious reasons, having to do with the cabal of villains and their plot. Other threads involve a cop, a scientist, and some kind of action-antihero who joins a team of conspirators in Green Idaho (a breakaway state). There's a pyramid in Green Idaho where people are being kept in cryogenic suspension. The conspiracy is involved with the pyramid.

From sfreviews.net:

> In a world where people routinely transform their bodies and minds to adapt, people who are able to cope without therapies and enhancements have an advantage ... some of these "naturals" conspire to return civilization to the good old days ... They manage to incorporate a flaw into the trillions of nanotech devices that have changed people, so that those devices simply expire in a catastrophic variant of the Y2K problem. People begin breaking down as physical and mental enhancements they have relied on now malfunction.

Also

> There's an AI based on insect minds, created by the conspiracy, for some reason. There are also swarms of genetically-engineered bees, created by a mad scientist, for some reason. The conspirators are planning to wait (in suspended animation?), till ... something to do with society changing with the nanobots sabotaged. (Hope I wasn't too long-winded.)

Answer (score 2):

The humans in the Slant society in America were dependent upon nanotech suppression of various character flaws, often correcting children's antics with nanotechnology in their brains and bodies.  The conspirators knew that the technology only covered up the character flaws, or even bad parenting, it did not actually correct them.  So the nanotech was prone to be hacked in the future by AI and others, and nearly everyone had the nanotechnology.

So the conspirators wanted to "release" everyone's nanotech suppression, which would result in a lot of crazy people, even insane people, running around, which would "cleanse" society and get rid of the weak, etc.  Combined with the hive mind correcting children's character flaws before they happened, humans could develop into a new society.  The conspirators put themselves into suspended animation until after all the flawed people destroyed the world and themselves.  Then they would emerge and make a hive mind future.

Comment: Thanks.
But what was with the bees?

Comment: And how did Jack Giffey (and his original identity) fit into this plot?

Comment: For the bees, it was hive mind examples.  For Jack Giffey, I'd have to re-read the book.